# Planes, quadric surfaces and then ...?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If planes are described as:
 $\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0})=0$

And quadric surfaces can be described as: 
$\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = 0$ (with $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x && y && z && 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is a symmetric matrix)

Then what is the name and compact form for a surface in the form of $Ax^3 + By^3 + Cz^3 + Dx^2z + \ldots = 0$

Comment: Cubic hypersurface.

Comment: @Sanchez, is cubic *hyper*surface still applicable when the polynomial is still an implicit function of three variables?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add - @Sanchez, if you answer the above comment, and provide a compact form for the equations, add it an an answer and you'll have yourself a nice easy accepted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is cubic hypersurface. (Hypersurface generally means something of one lower dimension, so it's not relevant whether your equation is implicit. I would also call your quadratic surface as quadratic hypersurface and plane as hyperplane once we move to higher dimensions. It's okay for you to remove "hyper" though.)

I don't think there is a more compact form for the equation, although naively you can do a change of variable to cancel out a few coefficients.

Comment: Now that I know what to look for [Algebraic Surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_surface) is a good place to start of surfaces of other orders.  Also, [Cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_surface) [Surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSurface.html) yields further results that are not [Cubic _hyper_ surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_form).